# Wrapping __TransparentProxy of RemotingProxy in another Proxy throws RemotingException

Tags: c#, remoting, realproxy

**Goal**

I have a couple of interfaces and some dlls that provide implementations for these interfaces. I want to load the implementation into a new AppDomain (so I can unload the dll later) and instatiate the implementation in the new AppDomain and then use a clientside(here the default AppDomain) proxy to wrap the actual implementation object. The goal is to create these `ClientProxy` instances once and change their actual implementations whenever while not loading the implementations assembly into the default AppDomain.

**Problem**

When calling a method on the ClientProxy __TransparentProxy object that gets another ClientProxy as argument I get the following Exceptions:

System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: 
`'The argument type 'System.MarshalByRefObject' cannot be converted into parameter type 'IData'.'`

With inner Exception:

InvalidCastException: `Object must implement IConvertible.`

When passing the __TransparentProxy obtained directly from the Server AppDomain the ClientProxy works.

**Setup**

Cloneable from: https://github.com/mailgerigk/remoting

Interfaces:

```
public interface IData
{
    int Foo { get; set; }
}

public interface ILogic
{
    void Update(IData data);
}
```

Interface Impl in _impl.dll:

```
public class DataImpl : MarshalByRefObject, IData
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

public class LogicImpl : MarshalByRefObject, ILogic
{
    public void Update(IData data)
    {
        data.Foo++;
    }
}
```

Serverside AssemblyLoader:

```
class AssemblyLoader : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public Assembly Assembly { get; private set; }

    public AssemblyLoader(string assemblyFile)
    {
        Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);
    }

    public object CreateInstance(string typeName)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetType(typeName));
    }
}
```

ClientProxy:

```
class ClientProxy : RealProxy
{
    private RealProxy innerProxy;

    public ClientProxy(Type interfaceType, object proxyObject)
        : base(interfaceType)
    {
        SetInnerProxy(proxyObject);
    }

    public void SetInnerProxy(object proxyObject)
    {
        innerProxy = RemotingServices.GetRealProxy(proxyObject);
    }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        return innerProxy.Invoke(msg);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ImplDomain", null,
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath,
            true);

        var assmblyLoader = app.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
            typeof(AssemblyLoader).Assembly.Location, typeof(AssemblyLoader).FullName,
            false, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null,
            new object[]
            {
                "_impl.dll"
            },
            null, null) as AssemblyLoader;

        var dataImpl = assmblyLoader.CreateInstance("DataImpl") as IData;
        var logicImpl = assmblyLoader.CreateInstance("LogicImpl") as ILogic;

        logicImpl.Update(dataImpl); // Works
        Console.WriteLine(dataImpl.Foo); // prints 1

        var clientDataProxy = new ClientProxy(typeof(IData), dataImpl);
        var clientDataImpl = clientDataProxy.GetTransparentProxy() as IData;

        var clientLogicProxy = new ClientProxy(typeof(ILogic), logicImpl);
        var clientLogicImpl = clientLogicProxy.GetTransparentProxy() as ILogic;

        clientLogicImpl.Update(dataImpl); // Works
        Console.WriteLine(clientDataImpl.Foo); // prints 2

        clientLogicImpl.Update(clientDataImpl); // throws System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException
        Console.WriteLine(clientDataImpl.Foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: This very vaguely rings a bell from somewhere when I was playing with proxies. I think you need to implement `IRemotingTypeInfo` and implement the `CanCastTo` member (even though you've already specified the `IData` interface in the constructor). Disclaimer: I could be wildly off base. Even if I am, though, you may be able to gleam more about what's happening by setting a breakpoint there.

Comment: I tried that before `CanCastTo` gets called 4 times on the `DataImpl` proxy with the `fromType` arguments: 2x`ContextBoundObject` then 2x`AppDomain`. Handing the call down to the impl proxy results in all 4 returning `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your reasoning, from the example code provided, the ClientProxy class appears unnecessary since you could get the same behaviour just by using a `RealProxy` directly:

```
var clientDataProxy = RemotingServices.GetRealProxy(dataImpl);
```

That being said, you can of course create your own concrete `RealProxy` and have it work as expected - you are just missing an override to get the TransparentProxy from the `innerProxy`:

```
class ClientProxy : RealProxy
{
    ... everything else ...

    public override object GetTransparentProxy() => innerProxy.GetTransparentProxy();

    public object GetOuterTransparentProxy() => base.GetTransparentProxy();
}

...
var clientDataProxy = new ClientProxy(typeof(IData), dataImpl);
var clientDataImpl = clientDataProxy.GetOuterTransparentProxy() as IData;

var clientLogicProxy = new ClientProxy(typeof(ILogic), logicImpl);
var clientLogicImpl = clientLogicProxy.GetOuterTransparentProxy() as ILogic;
...
```

As it stands, your `ClientProxy` is returning a `TransparentProxy` to the outer object.

**Edit:** Based on the explanation in the comments I have added a secondary `GetOuterTransparentProxy` method that returns the outer base implementation. This would still allow the OOTB `RealProxy.Invoke` implementation to be used, while exposing the outer `TransparentProxy` to be reused.

Comment: The reason for the `ClientProxy` is the ability to load another Impl Assembly without invalidating the `clientDataImpl/clientLogicImpl` instances (and all the references to them) and to then unload the AppDomain with the previously used Impl Assembly. By returning the `innerProxy.GetTransparentProxy()` the references to the TransparentProxy will become invalid when unloading their Remote AppDomain. What I want to do is "delegate" all method calls to the currently loaded Impl Proxy. This works as long as I don't pass another `ClientProxy` as method argument (see clientLogicImpl.Update calls).

Comment: @prydain That helps to explain the desired result; however I believe that would require overriding the Invoke method to understand the configuration (not a small task). I have a simple alternative to expose both proxies shown in the Edit above.